# Follow path of curve while the curve is drawn

Tags: python, modifiers, curve-modifier

I have a complicated curve, where the spline length is not aligned with the resolution of sample points. I animate the curve with the `bevel_factor_end` value.

I needed to choose `bevel_factor_mapping_end = "RESOLUTION"` in order for the end of the chain of arrows (which are independently animated) exactly match with the end of the curve. (The matching is guaranteed mathematically, since the parameter of rotation for the arrow is also the parameter that parameterizes the curve.)

However, the `Follow_Path` modifier for the empty cannot be customized to this bevel_factor_mapping_end. You can see the center of the empty is far away from the end of the curve. This would be different, if I chose the default `bevel_factor_mapping_end="SPLINE"`.

Hopefully, this question is not too technical and someone can help me out. It is really important for zooming in with the camera that the empty is exactly at the end of the curve.

The image should show the problem (the orange dot shows the location of the empty on the curve during follow path)

[image]

Comment: `bevel_factor_end`? `bevel_factor_mapping_end`? Are you doing this in Python? The tags under the question say "modifiers" and "curve-modifier" but I don't think those settings exist in the modifier... please use the "python" tag as well if this question is about python - this helps filtering out questions for dumb people like who are not good at python ;) Or use the names the settings have in the modifier so that one can identify them just by looking at them. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm working in python for most of the things that you see in this image. To synchronize arrows and the curve, I had to choose for the animation of the curve ```bevel_factor_mapping_end="RESOLUTION"``` instead of the default ```SPLINE```. With the default, the follow_path modifier of the Empty exactly sticks to the end of the curve. With the other option, it does not as you can see in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved easily using Geometry Nodes. This is the result that I have received using random speeds and lengths:

[image]

This is the node setup:

[image]

Repeat zone in center rotates vectors.

[image]

Simulation zone gets the last position and set it to curve point with index that matches frame number:

[image]

I think you can replace random generators by preparing initial set of points and save rotation speeds in attribute using Python.

Here is the file to play with:

[image]